# Is there a way to fix an order on executing a script with multiple sections on Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a script with multiple sections and I was wondering if there was a way to fix an order of executing the sections. For example :
Section 1, 2 and 3 ==> sometimes I want section 2 to be executed before 1 or 3 before 1 or any other order.

The sections are independent, and there's way more than 3 sections, that's why I can't execute one by one.

Thanks in advance, and please accept my apologies if there's a trivial way because I am not an expert.

Comment: (I began my question with "Hi" , stackoverflow deleted it I don't know why)

Comment: See this about your comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251077/my-opening-hi-everyone-in-my-question-keeps-disappearing

Answer (score 1):

Two options I can think of:

1. Make each one of your sections a [function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) and then call your functions in whichever order you like.  This may not be a "pretty" solution if you happen to have a lot of workspace variables that you need to add as arguments to and outputs from these functions but is possible.
2. Separate your sections into different files and call each script in the order that is needed.  This is very similar to option 1 but may work better if you have a lot of workspace variables that you don't want to pass around.

---

An example of option 2 would be:

originalfile.m

```
%% section 1
do stuff here

%% section 2
do different stuff here

%% section 3
do even more different stuff here
```

dothings.m

```
section2
section1
section3
```

section1.m

```
%% section 1
do stuff here
```

section2.m

```
%% section 2
do different stuff here
```

section3.m

```
%% section 3
do even more different stuff here
```

Comment: alright thanks, I thought about this solution but indeed it is not the prettiest, so I was wondering if there was something already implemented on Matlab, thanks !

Comment: Separating out the sections into separate files is likely the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MATLAB R2016b or later, you can turn each of your code sections into a function, then call those functions in the order you want:

```matlab
section1;
section2;
section3;

function section1()
%% original code for section 1 here
end

function section2()
%% original code for section 2 here
end

function section3()
%% original code for section 3 here
end
```

Now you can re-order the function calls at the top of the file as you want, which is likely easier than reorder all the code in your script.

However, if data gets passed between sections, you will need to include the relevant variables as input and output arguments to your functions, ant it might be a bit of work to figure out exactly which variables are relevant.

Comment: Thanks, As I said to John, I thought about this solution, but I wanted to check if there was something already implemented on matlab, I think for now it's the easiest way, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is an abuse of the test framework to fi your use case, but since they are independent you can leverage [script based tests](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/write-script-based-unit-tests.html). This will allow you to create a test suite which is an array corresponding to each (test) section. You can then reorder that array to your hearts content and call run on the suite (or run it in parallel)